Building a dataset for classification
I'm thinking of building a powershell script classifier using different architectures of neural networks. I have approximately 6k powershell scripts (3k malicious, 3k benign). My questions are: How should I approach this dataset? How should I preprocces it? Would be useful if I access the AST of the script and create more features (for example: the number of calls of a certain function)?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
